# synchronization and cuda scalability

Tags: cuda, synchronization, scalability

I have read that CUDA prevents synchronization between threads from different blocks to allow scalability. How is that even if increasing the number of MP in a device will increase execution speed either threads were synchronized in the same block or between different blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two related things to consider.

1. **Scalability** goes in both directions, up *and* down.  The desire is that your CUDA program be able to run on a GPU other than the one(s) it was "designed" for.  This implies it might be running on a larger GPU or on a smaller GPU.  Suppose I had a synchronization requirement among 128 threadblocks (out of perhaps a larger program), which all must execute concurrently in order to exchange data and satisfy the synchronization requirement, before any of them can complete.    If I run this program on a GPU with 16 SMs, each of which can schedule up to 16 threadblocks, its reasonable to conclude the program *might* work, since the momentary capacity of the GPU is 256 threadblocks.  But if I run the program on a GPU with 4 SMs, each of which can schedule 16 threadblocks, there is no circumstance under which the program can sensibly complete.
2. CUDA **Scheduling** will interfere (to some degree) with desired program execution.  There is no guaranteed or specified order in which the CUDA scheduler may schedule threadblocks.  Therefore, extending the above example, let's say for an 8 SM GPU (128 threadblocks momentary capacity), it might be that 127 of my 128 critical threadblocks get scheduled, while at the same time other, non-synchronization-critical threadblocks are scheduled. The 127 critical threadblocks will occupy 127 of the 128 available "slots", leaving only 1 slot remaining to process other threadblocks.  The 127 critical threadblocks may well be idle, waiting for threadblock 128 to appear, consuming slots but not necessarily doing useful work.  This will bring the performance of the GPU to a very low level, until the 128th threadblock eventually gets scheduled.

These are some examples of reasons why it is desirable not to have inter-threadblock synchronization requirements in the design of a CUDA program.